# What does this Mac-1 code mean?

Tags: computer-science, organization

This is a instructions to execute Mac-1 instructions (micro programming):

```
100: alu := ac; if z then goto 0;
101: sp := sp + (-1);
102: mar := sp; mbr := pc; wr;
103: pc := band(ir,amask); wr; goto 0;
```

Can someone tell me what it is doing and why it is doing it? All I know is line 100, which checks if the content of accumulator is zero. If it is zero it jumps to subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Line 101 manipulates the stack pointer (at least that's what `sp` looks like)
Line 103 looks like it's changing the program pointer (that's what `pc` looks to be).

As to the specifics, sorry, no idea what `wr`, `mar` and `mbr` are, so would need more context.

Off-hand, it looks like part of one of "take an interrupt" or "perform a function call" (more probbaly the former than the latter).